# How many runs are needed?

Tags: c++

A person can carry 'x' kg. That person must move 'y' items of different weights. If multiple items can be combined and carried in one go, how many runs are needed?

Here's what I think the beginning of code should look:

```
#include "Item.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
  Item A[10];
  int t; 
  string name1; int weight1;
  ifstream read("File.txt");
  read >> t;
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++){
      read >> name1 >> weight1;
      A[i].Set(name1, weight1);
    }
  read.close();
  //find maximum weight item:
  int r = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++){
     if (A[i].GetWeight() > A[r].GetWeight())
     r = i;
    }
     int maxItemWeight = A[r].GetWeight();
     cout << A[r].GetWeight();

    int carryWeight = 100; //How much weight a person can carry at once
    int times; // Times to carry all the items

    if (maxItemWeight > carryWeight)
        cout << "It's impossible to carry all the items " << endl;
    else {
          //Any advice for this part????
     }


    cout << "Times to carry all the items: " << times << endl;
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: You should put your question in the main text rather than just leaving it in a comment within the code.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you described the problem or issue you are having instead of just the skeleton of your code expecting someone to fill it in.

Comment: Show us what have you tried.

Comment: I don't expect you to fill it, I'm looking for some hints. I've already showed what my solution with 3 items is.

Comment: Think about how you would solve it on paper.  You know you have `n` packages of different weights, and the carrier has a carrying capacity of 60 KG.  How do you do it?

Comment: Hint: Starting with the *largest* item, find the *next* largest item you can add to it without exceeding your limit. Repeat this until no items can be added. With those items removed (shipped/carried/whatever), repeat the entire thing on the remaining items until there are none left.

Comment: Your 'solution' for 3 items is wrong. `&&`s should be `||`s.

Comment: @WhozCraig - is that approach optimal?

Comment: @Roddy No, it isn't. Only exhaustive analysis will guarantee an optimal solution, but it will likely be close to what the OP needs for a homework assignment (unless the assignment *requires* optimal portioning). Via sorting the algorithm I presented is close, but it won't be *guaranteed* optimal.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you start by putting items into bins, each of which can contain 60 kg at most. Once you've placed all of the items into bins you know exactly how many trips are needed. Simply count the number of bins used.

Here's a lousy algorithm: Put an item into the first bin into which it will fit. It's O(n), so it's fast. Suppose your array contains six 10 kg items and then six 50 kg items. This algorithm will place those first six 10 kg items in one bin, filling it to capacity. The remaining six items have to go in separate bins, so seven bins overall. If you had simply attacked the problem from the other end you would have found the optimal solution of six bins, and hence six trips. This algorithm can at times overstate the number of bins by a factors of two.

Sorting helps, but it does not guarantee optimality. Any polynomial time algorithm can overstate the number of bins needed by 22%. Sorting is the key to reaching that 22% figure. An optimal solution has to exhaust all possible arrangements. You can use backtracking to accomplish this. On the other hand, an O(n*log(n)) algorithm that comes within 22% of optimal might well be good enough.

If you google "bin packing problem" you will find a lot of literature on this problem because this problem has lots of industrial applications.

Answer (score 1):

I might start by picking up the heaviest item first.  Then find the next heaviest item you can pick up.  Continue searching until you can't pick up any more items.  Save that configuration.

Drop everything but the first item.  Find the 2nd heaviest item you can pick up.  Continue searching until you can't pick up any more.

Keep looping like this, saving each configuration, and then actually carry the configuration with the most number of packages.  If there is a tie, carry the combination with the heaviest single item.

I don't claim this is optimal, but I think it should work.

Comment: It's not optimal. Yours is an O(n*log(n)) algorithm because of the sort. The rest of your algorithm is O(n), so it's O(n*log(n)) overall. Any polynomial time algorithm is suboptimal. This is the NP-complete bin packing problem.

Comment: @DavidHammen:  This is just what I came up with after thinking about it for 15 seconds.  I was just looking for a working solution, not an optimal one.  If you could provide an optimal solution, I'd upvote it.

Comment: Given any polynomial time algorithm, one can always find a configuration where the algorithm will be off by 22%. Exhaustive search yields an optimal solution, but that's an exponential time algorithm. Avoiding what are essentially duplicative solutions will cut down on the magnitude of the search but not on the nature of the search. You need an exponential time algorithm to guarantee optimality.